# How to create hmac_md5 hash value from the shared code using fatzebra payment gateway

Tags: php

I am using **Fatzebra** payment gateway.

I have a **shared code** for example **234567erty**.

I need to convert the **shared code** into a **hash value** using **hmac_md5** in **php**.

hash_hmac didn't not solve my problem as it uses three parameters.

[This is the link to the fatzebra doc showing details about hash from secret code.](https://docs.pmnts.io/display/DOC/Hosted+Payment+Page)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the hash_hmac() function.

```
$input  = 'anything';
$key    = '234567erty';
$output = hash_hmac('md5', $input, $key);
```

$key is your secret key

Comment: the value in $code is my secret code

Comment: ok, I changed it.

Comment: No it did'nt work

Comment: this is the only way you can solve using hmac_md5